# Time rate problem involving trains don't know if my answer is correct

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics

Suppose trains leave from NY for AT every 20 mins starting at 1:00 am, and trains leave AT for NY every 30 mins starting at 1:10 am. If it takes each train 10 hours to travel from one city to the other, how many trains traveling from AT to NY are passed by the train that leaves NY at 1 pm and arrives in AT at 11 pm?

So every 30 mins:

- 1:10 am
- 1:40 am
- 2:10 am
- ...
- 12:40 pm
- 1:10 pm
- ...
- 10:40pm

In 10 hours from 12:40 pm > 10:40 pm since 10hrs = 600 mins 600/30 = 20 trains passes when that single train travels from NY to AT from 1pm to 11pm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an equation. Given the problem parameters every train AT→NY that leaves from the time the NY→AT train leaves (and until it arrives) qualifies.

The decimal time notation for $30$ mins is $0.5$ (hour), and 1:10 is $1$ hour + $\dfrac{10}{60}$ hour, or $\dfrac{7}{6}$ hour. We can write the "$t^{th}$ train number leaving" equation, that gives the departure time for all trains AT→NY

$$\dfrac{7}{6}+0.5\cdot t$$

Then we want to know how many trains leave between $13$h ($1$pm) and $23$h ($11$pm), that is all the $t$ that meet

$$13 \le \dfrac{7}{6}+0.5\cdot t\lt 23$$

or $$\dfrac{71}{3}\le t\lt \dfrac{131}{3}$$thus $$t=\dfrac{131}{3}-\dfrac{71}{3}=20$$

Comment: very neat answer, thanks for teaching me new ways of doing math 

Comment: The notation here could use some work. *t* is an index variable, and you want to find the cardinality of the set of *t*'s that satisfy your penultimate equation. 20 is the right answer, but the way you've set up the problem, *t* does not equal 20. *t* = {1,2,3,...,20} - it's a set whose *size* is 20. Saying *t* =20 is incompatible with your penultimate equation.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to see it is that the train that leaves NY at $1$ PM will pass all the trains that leave AT before $11$ PM.  That is all the trains that leave from $1:10$ PM through $10:40$ PM.  There are $20$ of them.

Comment: This is the simplest way to think about it. 20 trains leave AT over the course of 10 hours (no matter what time of the hour they leave), and the NY-AT train passes all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Writing $0110$ for 1:10 am and $1310$ for 1:10 pm,
the trains leave AT at $0110,$ $0140,$ $0210$, $0240, \ldots ,$
and we want to know how many of these trains pass (and are passed by) the train that leaves NY at $1300.$

The train that leaves AT at $0240$ arrives in NY at $1240$ and therefore does not pass the train that leaves NY at $1300.$
But the train that leaves AT at $0310$ arrives in NY at $1310$ and therefore passes the train that leaves NY at $1300.$

Since the train that leaves NY at $1300$ arrives in AT at $2300,$ it passes the train that leaves AT at $2240$ but not the train that leaves AT at $2310.$

So now we know the first and last trains from AT that pass the $1300$ from NY.
Count those two trains and all trains in between.